# UIDatePicker returns current date, even when I pick a different date

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

So I have a method where I change the keyboard to a UIDatePicker, and I want the user to select the date to set a reminder. So far I have the keyboard swap to a UIDatePicker, and when I print out the date string it only prints the current date, regardless of what I set.

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

[self.noteTextView becomeFirstResponder];
[self.noteTextView setInputView:self.datePicker];

NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

self.myDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; //a string of the date that I want to use in other methods

NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: have you created property with IBOutlet? if yes the don't perform alloc and init, because it will create another instance of UIDatePicker and your date selection will not affect on current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default date of UIDatePicker is the current date and that is what you are printing. For picked date use

```
[self.myDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", strDate);
}
```

Comment: This helped alot with a similar issue I had with iOS 12 Beta 8-9 where getting the date for a date picker returned the default date. This had worked before in iOS11.